# Multiple selectors: identify the triggering one?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

Here's a very small issue that I was unable to figure out. I'm sure someone can answer in no time:

Having multiple selectors like

```
$('a.button, span.xyz, a.another').click(function(e) {
   var clicked_element = ???;
});
```

, how can I figure out which selector was actually clicked? I need to use it like `$(clicked_element)...`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using $(this) will get you the element that was clicked..  and using [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) can help you determine what was clicked.

```js
$('a.button, span.xyz, a.another').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).is("a.button")) {
    alert("a.button was clicked");
  } else if ($(this).is("span.xyz")) {
    alert("span.xyz was clicked");
  } else if ($(this).is("a.another")) {
    alert("a.another was clicked");
  }
});
```

---

**Edited:**

As I wrote up this answer it seems there is a better approach.  Patrick DW's comment intrigued me and I wanted to know more.  His clarification is here [jQuery - Issues with combining selectors in a single event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315308/jquery-issues-with-combining-selectors-in-a-single-event-handler)

This would be a better approach

```js
$("a.button").click(function(e) { ... });
$("span.xyz").click(function(e) { ... });
$("a.another").click(function(e) { ... });
```

As I understand it if your goal was to place common functionality in one spot then this is how it should be handled

```js
function commonFunctionality(elementSelector) {
  // common code for all elements here or at the end

  switch (elementSelector) {
    case "a.button":
      //do stuff for a.button only;
      break;
    case "span.xyz":
      //do stuff for span.xyz only;
      break;
    case "a.another":
      //do stuff for a.another only;
      break;
  }

  // common code for all elements
}


$("a.button").click(function(e) { ... });
$("span.xyz").click(function(e) { ... });
$("a.another").click(function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: @bobsoap.  Your welcome, please don't forget to accept the correct answer.

Comment: Trouble with this is that it is effectively combining the inefficiency that `.delegate()` suffers (testing against a selector) with the inefficiency of assigning multiple redundant handlers. So you get the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @Patrick DW... could you explain more.  I believe your saying I should break up the click handlers into separate statements?  is this correct? if so why?

Comment: @Patrick DW ... I have posted a question here to get an answer from you regarding these inefficiencies.  Could you explain in more detail for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315308/issues-with-combining-selectors-in-a-event-handler

Comment: @John - Yes, it would make more sense to break them up into  separate handlers, and place any common functionality they share into a named function that can be called from within the handlers. This eliminates the need to run the `.is()` tests at every event occurrence, which can be costly. It can sometimes be beneficial to test for the element that was clicked. This is what `.delegate()` does. You suffer the expense of the test, but gain from the reduced number of handlers being assigned.

Comment: @bobsoap... It would be good to read my edited answer as it provides deeper insight to your problem. It would also be nice that you give @Patrick DW some credit on his answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315308/issues-with-combining-selectors-in-a-event-handler

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but the other thought is that you can easily bind more than one handler to an event. So a common handler can be assigned to all 3 elements, then separate handlers can be assigned for each specific element.  I'm not sure what order each event will be called in or if they're guaranteed to be called in any particular order, but that is one way of giving a bunch of elements common behaviour.

Comment: @Allan Niehuis .. but as Patrick added it it not efficient to handle the events in one handler and use is() to determine what was clicked.  Essentially with jQuery you are testing what element was clicked twice.  Once by jQuery and again by using .is().

Comment: @John - I would have accepted the answer right away but I had to wait 7 minutes :) Did it now. I also checked out what you and @Patrick added, thanks for that. Putting common functionality into its own function seems the way to go here.

Comment: On a side note, I'd never have guessed that such a seemingly simple question would spark such a great debate. Kudos to all who chimed in.

Answer (score 2):

The element which triggers an event is available within the function as `$(this)`, i.e.

```
$('a.button, span.xyz, a.another').click(function(e) {
   var clicked_element = $(this);
});
```

You can also test to identify if the element matches a particular selector using [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if ($(this).is('a.button'))) { ... }
```

Comment: Right... But I need to use it in an if-condition and would like to avoid using `hasClass` or so. I need to do something like `if(clicked_element == 'a.button') {} else if(clicked_element == 'span.xyz')`. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: If you actually want to do _different_ things for each element, I'd recommend you actually bind a different click handler for each!

Comment: @bobsoap - I'd agree with Dexter. If these elements are to have different functionality, then I'd assign different handlers instead of adding the overhead of testing each one at each event. If there's some common functionality, then roll that into its own function, and call it from the individual handlers. If these are all in the same container, then event delegation may be the better solution. That way you're trading the overhead of testing the element for a reduced number of handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Patrick and Dexter about separating these elements if they have different functionality. But if you are going to use this method, try using some of the built in javascript methods. I don't know what the HTML markup looks like, but assuming this markup, you can try the script below:

```
<a class="button" href="http://somesite.com">Some Site</a>
<span class="xyz">span</span>
<a class="another" href="/topics/topic2.html">Topic 2</a>

$('a.button, span.xyz, a.another').click(function(e) {
   var clicked = 'a.another';
   if (this.tagName == "SPAN") { clicked = 'span.xyz'; }
   if (this.href.match('somesite')) { clicked = 'a.button'; }
   // Do something
});
```

Comment: This is similar to my answer on Johns additional post.  I couldn't agree more, using native dom scripting for this type of this is remarkably faster and often easier to understand as well.